# How can I know what the value of the <input/> will be on keypressed?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have an event listener on the "keypress" event:

`input.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) { ... }`

When I read the value of the input field, it is not updated yet. Is there a way to know what the value of the input will be before waiting for the "keyup" event?

Note: I tried to use a `setTimeout(function() { ... }, 1);` but it doesn't work with copy/paste (the input value is not updated). when I set the timeout to 10ms it does work in my tests but it doesn't feel like a robust solution (may depend on the speed of the hardware).

Comment: Perhaps the keyup event would report the updated value? Also, the [input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) seems more robust - you can check `e.target.value` in the handler.

Comment: The `keydown` event will trigger each time you push down on a key. If you type 'hi' it will trigger twice. Each time the value of the input will be missing only the currently pressed key. You can get which key is pressed right now from the event parameter. Am i right?

Comment: Event object have may properties which you can use as mentioned, like, `e.target.value`, `e.key`, `e.keyCode` etc. Use as per need.

These links might help. 
https://javascript.info/keyboard-events                     http://keycode.info/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps a more robust solution will be to listen to the `input` event? However, this will not capture *all* keyboard events that will not change/mutate the value of the input (e.g. pressing the `Home`/`End` button):

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.value);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

Alternatively, if you *really* want to depend on keyboard events, then `keyup` is the event you want to listen to, since it is fired after the key has been lifted:

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.value);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: @H.Udara You're missing the point. When `keydown`/`keypress` events are fired, the input may not have necessarily received the character yet, which means `e.target.value` does not reflect the desired value expected by OP.